# KNN algorithm from OCR project having trouble with certain digits

Tags: python, ocr, knn

Im trying to code a OCR project to identify digits without using any extra libraries. Im using Pygame to draw and render the number to identify. I managed to get all of it working, but for some weird reason, some specific numbers like 9 or 6 never ever get recognized by the algorithm(not even when I set the k really high, none of the possibilities is that number). I have absolutely no idea why, and any help would be really appreciated

```
import time
import pygame
from sys import exit
import random
import math
number_comparisons = 60000
DATA_DIR = r"C:/Users/----/Downloads/OCR/"
TEST_DIR = r"C:/Users/----/Downloads/OCR/test/"
TEST_DATA_FILENAME = DATA_DIR + "t10k-images.idx3-ubyte"
TEST_LABELS_FILENAME = DATA_DIR + "t10k-labels.idx1-ubyte"
TRAIN_DATA_FILENAME = DATA_DIR + "train-images.idx3-ubyte"
TRAIN_LABELS_FILENAME = DATA_DIR + "train-labels.idx1-ubyte"
start_time = time.time()
DEBUG = True
#starts pygame (images and sounds)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
#create screen variable
width = 784
height = 850
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

#ponerle titulo
pygame.display.set_caption("Optical Character Recognition")

#reloj/framerate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def read_labels(filename,n_max_labels = None):
    labels = [] #variable que guarda todas las imagenes
    with open(filename, "rb") as f: #abrir el fichero filename como f, y leerlo en binario ("rb")
        _  =f.read(4) #numero inutil (representa algo que no necesitamos)
        #los siguientes 12 bytes representan el numero de imagenes, el numero de filas y de columnas
        n_labels = bytes_to_int(f.read(4))
        if n_max_labels:
            n_labels = n_max_labels
        for label_idx in range(n_labels):
            label = f.read(1)
            labels.append(label)
            
    return labels

count = 0

def read_images(filename,n_max_images = None):
    global count
    images = [] #variable que guarda todas las imagenes
    with open(filename, "rb") as f: #abrir el fichero filename como f, y leerlo en binario ("rb")
        _  =f.read(4) #numero inutil (representa algo que no necesitamos)
        #los siguientes 12 bytes representan el numero de imagenes, el numero de filas y de columnas
        n_images = bytes_to_int(f.read(4))
        if n_max_images:
            n_images = n_max_images
        n_rows = bytes_to_int(f.read(4))
        n_columns = bytes_to_int(f.read(4))
        for image_idx in range(n_images):
            image = []#variable que guarda la imagen actual
            for row_idx in range(n_rows):
                row = []#variable que guarda la columna actual
                for column_idx in range(n_columns):
                    count += 1
                    pixel = f.read(1) #leemos el pixel actual de 8 bits y lo apendizamos a la row
                    row.append(pixel)
                image.append(row)#metemos la row en la image
            images.append(image)#metemos la image en el conjunto de images
    return images

def bytes_to_int(byte_data):
    if byte_data == 0:
        return 0
    elif byte_data == 200:
        return 255
    elif byte_data == 200:
        return 200
    else:
        return int.from_bytes(byte_data,"big")

def pasar_lista_unidimensional(X):
    lista = []
    for i in range(len(X)):
        for j in range(len(X[0])):
            lista.append(X[i][j])
    return [lista]
def pasar_lista_unidimensional2(X):
    return [aplanar_lista(sample) for sample in X]
def aplanar_lista(l):
    return [pixel for sublist in l for pixel in sublist]
def dist(x,y):
    temp2 = []
    for x_i,y_i in zip(x,y):
        temp2.append((bytes_to_int(x_i) - bytes_to_int(y_i)) **2)
    return sum(temp2)**0.5
    return sum((bytes_to_int(x_i) - bytes_to_int(y_i)) **2 for x_i,y_i in zip(x,y))**0.5 #distancia euclides
def distancia_entre_samples(X_train,test_sample):
    return [dist(train_sample,test_sample) for train_sample in X_train] #por todas las imagenes, calculamos su distancia arriba

def most_frequent_element(list):
    return max(list, key= list.count)


def knn(X_train,y_train,X_test, k = 3):
    y_pred = [] #la prediccion que tenemos a los x_test
    print("Using the knn algorithm to determine k nearest numbers to drawing...")
    for test_sample_idx,test_sample in enumerate(X_test):
        training_distances = distancia_entre_samples(X_train,test_sample) #queremos conseguir las distancias a todos los puntos
        sorted_distance_indices = [
            pair[0]
            for pair in sorted(enumerate(training_distances), key = lambda x: x[1]) ]#escogemos la menor distancia
        candidates = [bytes_to_int(y_train[idx]) for idx in sorted_distance_indices[:k]] # k mejores candidatos
        print("Top k choices were", candidates)
        top_candidate = most_frequent_element(candidates)
        y_pred.append(top_candidate) #apuntamos a predicción
    return y_pred
def main():
    global X_test
    print("Reading training files...")
    #"X" es igual al dataset y "y" es el label asignado
    X_train = read_images(TRAIN_DATA_FILENAME,number_comparisons)
    y_train = read_labels(TRAIN_LABELS_FILENAME,number_comparisons)
    y_test = read_labels(TEST_LABELS_FILENAME,1)

    
    print("Converting drawing to 2D grid")
    X_train = pasar_lista_unidimensional2(X_train) #queremos pasar la matriz de valores a una matriz unidimensional
    y_pred = knn(X_train,y_train,X_test,15)
    print("The number you have just written is: " ,y_pred)
    print("Number of iterations: ", count)
image_array = []  
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 24) 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
for i in range(0,784,28):
    pygame.draw.line(screen,"white",(0,i),(784,i))
for j in range(0,width,28):
    image_array.append([0]*28)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,"white",(j,0),(j,784))
print(type(image_array),type(image_array[0]),type(image_array[0][0]))
def draw(x,y):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,"white",(x-x%28,y-y%28,28,28)) 
    image_array[math.trunc(y/28)][math.trunc(x/28)] = 200
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,"white",(x-x%28+28,y-y%28,28,28)) 
    if math.trunc(x/28)+1 < 28: image_array[math.trunc(y/28)][math.trunc(x/28)+1] = 200
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,"white",(x-x%28-28,y-y%28,28,28)) 
    if math.trunc(x/28)-1 >= 0:  image_array[math.trunc(y/28)][math.trunc(x/28)-1] = 200
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,"white",(x-x%28,y-y%28+28,28,28)) 
    if math.trunc(y/28)+1 < 28:  image_array[math.trunc(y/28)+1][math.trunc(x/28)] = 200
    
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,"white",(x-x%28,y-y%28-28,28,28)) 
    if math.trunc(y/28)-1 >= 0: image_array[math.trunc(y/28)-1][math.trunc(x/28)] = 200
    
button = False
text = font.render("Guess Number", True, (0, 0, 0))
while True:
    #para que se pueda cerrar
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.QUIT()
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            button = True
            
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            button = False
    if button == True:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if pos[1] < 756:
            draw(pos[0],pos[1])
        else:
            X_test = pasar_lista_unidimensional(image_array)
            print(X_test)
            print("Loading...")
            main()
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,"red",(0,784,784,66))
    pygame.display.update()
    
    #framerate
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: that's a lot of code. Please focus your question to the few lines of code that you think are not doing what they are supposed to do. Also supply an example image and desired results might get you the help you need on here